# How can I join 4 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Please help to modify the below code. I want to join these two select queries such that I can get a single output with records from two diff tables ? I have 4 tables,

table_a has the user id that I have to use to search

table_b1 has the foreign key for table_c which has the name that I want to get

table_b2 also has the foreign key for table_c which has the second name that I want to get too.

How can I combine below query in a single output?

**my code**

```
select c.name from table_a a 
join table_b1 b1 on a.id=b1.id
join table_c c on b1.pri_id=c.id where a.user='abc'

select c.name from table_a a 
join table_b2 b2 on a.id=b2.id
join table_c c on b2.pri_id=c.id where a.user='abc'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use UnionAll here like this,

```
select c.name from table_a a 
join table_b1 b1 on a.id=b1.id
join table_c c on b1.pri_id=c.id where a.user='abc'

union all

select c.name from table_a a
join table_b2 b2 on a.id=b2.id
join table_c c on b2.pri_id=c.id where a.user='abc'
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. But I want to make the query non-repetitive.

Comment: You could do the UNION ALL before joining the b tables, so in the first part of the query you could do:
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT b1.id, b1.pri_id FROM table_b1 b1 UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT b2.id, b2.pri_id FROM table_b2 b2) tb

Comment: Also, if you use UNION ALL, you get duplicates, i.e. pairs of ID-PRI_ID that are present in BOTH table_b1 and table_b2. If you only use UNION, the db performs internally an ORDER and DISTINCT getting rid of the duplicates, it adds to performance, but if you are not sure if you can get duplicates, it will eliminate them implicitly.

Comment: Thanks @AnaGH for the suggestion. Your answer has helped me clear my doubts. Although in this case, Manektech's answer would be more apt. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to extract the names information in table_c for tables table_b1 and table_b2, which also join to table_a by the id column.
You'll need to add table_c twice to your query to retrieve name from table_b1 and name from table_b2, because the conditions to retrieve the name are different.

If you only want names when **there is information in table_b1 AND table_b2** (and in table_c for each of the b tables), the query will be:

```sql
SELECT tc1.name name_b1, tc2.name name_b2
FROM table_a ta
    JOIN table_b1 tb1 ON ta.id = tb1.id
    JOIN table_b2 tb2 ON ta.id = tb2.id
    JOIN table_c tc1 ON tb1.pri_id = tc1.id
    JOIN table_c tc2 ON tb2.pri_id = tc2.id
WHERE ta.user = 'abc'
```

If there might not always be information for user in table_b1 or table_b2, but you want to retrieve information anyway, getting NULL when there isn't a name on one or both of the b tables, you'll need left joins:

```sql
SELECT tc1.name name_b1, tc2.name name_b2
FROM table_a ta
    LEFT JOIN table_b1 tb1 ON ta.id = tb1.id
    LEFT JOIN table_b2 tb2 ON ta.id = tb2.id
    LEFT JOIN table_c tc1 ON tb1.pri_id = tc1.id
    LEFT JOIN table_c tc2 ON tb2.pri_id = tc2.id
WHERE ta.user = 'abc'
```

Comment: I have just now realized that you want only one name column, not two, so @Manektech Knowledge Base answer would be more correct in that case. I leave my answer in case you have simplified too much your example and you are looking to something more in line with my answer.